# How to have better quoting in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

When replying email in rich text format, Gmail behaves like Outlook and encourages me to write the reply at the top. The problem is I want to write my reply between the paragraphs of the previous email text.

If I choose plain text, Gmail adds ">" on the left of each line, which is good, but the quoted text is kept as a single very long line of text. Gmail doesn't break the line into several lines after 70/80 characters.

Is there an option or plugin or tool to customize how Gmail quote previous email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, it turned out the problem was during switching from rich formatting to plain text:

- if previously I used plain text, Gmail will break long lines properly
- if previously I used rich formatting, Gmail will quote Outlook style, and when I press 'plain text', Gmail will reformat the reply to plain text, but long lines are not broken

So the solution if previously I chose rich formatting is:

- reply
- click 'plain text'
- discard
- reply again

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. When the timer expires, be sure to mark this as "accepted" so future querents will know this is a solvable problem.