# Gmail quotes in other clients

Tags: gmail, text-formatting

I recently sent an email reply through Gmail that included an inline quote from the previous message.

In Gmail, this displays as I'm accustomed to seeing quotes: purple text, vertical bar in the left margin.

The recipient was confused and didn't realize there was a quote. Investigating, I found that the raw text (by using "show original") has nothing to delineate that there is a quote. Is there a way to force Gmail to include a `>` to guarantee proper handling of the quote by recipients mail clients?

UPDATE:
I continue to have this problem. It appears that the plain text contains no quote information, but there is quote information in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to force Gmail to include a `>` to guarantee proper
>   handling of the quote by recipients mail clients?

Yes there is: Use plain text mode for writing your reply.

If you need rich text, instead tell your readers where begins and end a quote. The simplest way is just to be explicit about that you are including a quote.

**Example 1**  (use quotation marks)
Albert Einstein once he said: “We can not solve our problems with the same level of thinking that created them”

**Example 2**  (use --- or any other marker before and after the quoted text)

Albert Einstein once he said:
---
We can not solve our problems with the same level of thinking that created them
---

**References**
[How to have better quoting in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14938/how-to-have-better-quoting-in-gmail)